# Disable Kubernetes replica set load balancing

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I have a Kubernetes cluster of 3 nodes.

A sample deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

I do not have ingress, but I do have external load balancer that round-robins the traffic at `80.11.12.10`, `80.11.12.11`, `80.11.12.12`. So I set my service like this.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
  externalIPs:
    - 80.11.12.10
    - 80.11.12.11
    - 80.11.12.12
```

The problem is that due to existing kubernetes service load balancer the traffic get load balancing twice. Aside that it is unnecessary it is spoils the connection persistence. Is there a way to force Kubernetes to forward traffic on local machine pod for each node?

Answer (score 1):

If you set `service.spec.externalTrafficPolicy` to the value `Local`, kube-proxy only proxies proxy requests to local endpoints, and does not forward traffic to other nodes.

```
kubectl patch svc servicename -p '{"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Local"}}'
```

If there are no local endpoints, packets sent to the node are dropped.

For `clusterIP` type service you need to use [Service Topology](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service-topology/)

> Service Topology enables a service to route traffic based upon the
> Node topology of the cluster. For example, a service can specify that
> traffic be preferentially routed to endpoints that are on the same
> Node as the client, or in the same availability zone.

It's an alpha feature available from kubernetes 1.17 which needs to be turned on by [enabling the feature flag](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/enabling-service-topology/)

Comment: Tried to use "  topologyKeys: - "kubernetes.io/hostname". Did not work, no errors, any thoughts?

Comment: `{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Local"}` only works on NodePort or LoadBalancer so does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

`kube-proxy` is using `ipvs` in order to maange load-balancing in recent k8s versions. `ipvsadm` can be used at the node level in order to choose which load-balancing algorithm you want `ipvs` to use. According to https://linux.die.net/man/8/ipvsadm, you can choose between 8 load-balancing algorithms: round robin, weighted round robin, least-connection, weighted least-connection, locality-based least-connection, locality-based least-connection with replication, destination-hashing, and source-hashing. For additional information, check the documentation for the `--scheduler` option of `ipvsadm`.